# Why does Scala not have withFilterNot?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

In Scala collections like `Seq`, we have the methods `filter` and, for convenience, `filterNot`. The latter allow us to write e.g.

```
seq.filterNot(someSet.contains)
```

instead of the less elegant

```
seq.filter(e => !someSet.contains(e))
```

In addition to these methods, we have the `WithFilter` class to be able to evaluate a filtering condition lazily. Conveniently, the usage is the same as with `filter`:

```
seq.withFilter(e => !someSet.contains(e))
```

My question is: why don't we have a `withFilterNot` like this:

```
seq.withFilterNot(someSet.contains)
```

More specifically: is it just a feature considered to be unnecessary/low priority by the Scala developers, or is there a technical reason?

Comment: Scala provides many many ways to filter collections. It is never going to cover every use case.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic, unless a core contributor of the Scala programming language comes to answer, there is no way we could know why they decided not to provide such method. The discussion about why some methods aren't provide is old, for example take a look at [this discussion](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3690) about notContains in set - the short answer is you can alway use `!` to negate something and for many developers that's readable enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it even shorter: `seq.filterNot(someSet)`

As to `.withFilterNot`, you can easily add it yourself if you feel it is important to have:

```
object PimpSyntax {
   implicit class PimpedSeq[T](val seq: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
      def withFilterNot(filter: T => Boolean) = seq.withFilter(!f(_))
   }
}
```

Now, just `import PimpSyntax._`, and you can write things like `seq.withFilterNot(someSet)` all you like.

Or, even better:

```
 object PimpSyntax {
     implicit class Negator[T](val f: T => Boolean) extends AnyVal {
        def unary_!: T => Boolean = !f(_)
     }
 }
```

With this, you can not only do `seq.withFilter(!someSet)`, but also things like `seq.partition(!someSet)`, `seq.find(!someSet)`, `seq.dropWhile(!someSet)` etc.

Comment: This does at least implicitly answer the question whether there are technical reasons behind it.